# Oracle password verify function default

Tags: oracle, function, null, passwords, default

Do other profiles with the value `default` for parameter `password verify function` inherit settings from the default profile? How does it look like for oracle 10g, 11g, 12c.?

**Example:**
For default profile, the parameter has value `NULL`. Another profile has value `DEFAULT`. Does it mean that the other profiles also has `NULL`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Default refers to the default profile, whatever it has for the password verify function is used when the word 'default' is used in other profiles. This is a simple, useful way of enabling/disabling the verify function on development database copies. Have all the profiles use 'default', then substitute the verify function name or null as appropriate in the default profile.